Calculating the n-th power of any 2×2 matrix
Proposition. Suppose $(\mathcal Ω,+,\ast,•)$ is an algebraic structure, so that $(\mathcal Ω,+,\ast)$ is
a commutative ring with multiplicative identity $\pmb{1}$ and $(\mathcal Ω,+,•)$ is a vector space over an arbitrary field $\mathbb F$. If we're given $x \in \mathcal Ω$ such that $x^2=αx+β\pmb{1}$ for some $α,β \in \mathbb F$, then for all $m \in \mathbb N$
$$x^{2m+1}=\left(\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}α^{2(m-l)}β^l}\right)x+\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}α^{2(m-l)-1}β^l}\right)\pmb{1}$$
PROOF.(By induction on $m$) For $m=1$ the formula gives $x^3=(α^2+β)x+αβ\pmb{1}$, which can easily be concluded from the given equation, since $$x^3=(αx+β\pmb{1})x=αx^2+βx=α(αx+β\pmb{1})+βx=(α^2+β)x+αβ\pmb{1}.$$
As a sidenote, the formula holds for $m=0$ too.
Now, assume inductively that the formula holds for $m \in \mathbb N$. Therefore, we have that
$$x^{2m+3}=x^{2m+1}x^2=\left(\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}α^{2(m-l)}β^l}\right)x^3+\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}α^{2(m-l)-1}β^l}\right)x^2=\left(\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}α^{2(m-l)}β^l}\right)\left((α^2+β)x+αβ\pmb{1}\right)+\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}α^{2(m-l)-1}β^l}\right)\left(αx+β\pmb{1}\right)=\left(\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}α^{2m-2l+2}β^l}+\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}α^{2m-2l}β^{l+1}}+\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}α^{2m-2l}β^{l+1}}\right)x+\left( 
\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}α^{2m-2l+1}β^{l+1}}+\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}α^{2m-2l-1}β^{l+2}}\right)\pmb{1}=\left(α^{2m+2}+\sum_{l=1}^m{\left[\left(\binom{2m-l}{l}+\binom{2m-l}{l-1}\right)+ 
\binom{2m-l+1}{l-1}\right]α^{2m-2l+2}β^l}+β^{m+1}\right)x+\left(α^{2m+1}β+\sum_{l=1}^m{\left[\binom{2m-l}{l}+\binom{2m-l}{l-1}\right]α^{2m-2l+1}β^{l+1}}\right)\pmb{1}=\left(α^{2m+2}+\sum_{l=1}^m{\left[\binom{2m-l+1}{l}+ 
\binom{2m-l+1}{l-1}\right]α^{2m-2l+2}β^l}+β^{m+1}\right)x+\left(α^{2m+1}β+\sum_{l=1}^m{\binom{2m-l+1}{l}α^{2m-2l+1}β^{l+1}}\right)\pmb1=\left(\binom{2(m+1)}{0}α^{2(m+1)}+\sum_{l=1}^m{\binom{2(m+1)-l}{l}α^{2(m+1)-2l}β^l}+\binom{m+1}{m+1}β^{m+1}\right)x+\left(\binom{2(m+1)-1}{0}α^{2m+1}β+\sum_{l=1}^{(m+1)-1}{\binom{2(m+1)-l-1}{l}α^{2(m+1)-2l-1}β^{l+1}}\right)\pmb{1}=\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m+1}{\binom{2(m+1)-l}{l}α^{2(m+1)-2l}β^l}\right)x+\left(\sum_{l=0}^{(m+1)-1}{\binom{2(m+1)-l-1}{l}α^{2(m+1)-2l-1}β^{l+1}}\right)\pmb{1}$$
$ο.ε.δ.$
From the above one can extract a similar formula for even powers. In particular, for all positive integers $m$
$$x^{2m}=\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}α^{2(m-l)-1}β^l}\right)x+\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2(m-1)-l}{l}α^{2(m-l-1)}β^{l+1}}\right)\pmb{1}.$$
APPLICATION
If  $\mathcal Ω=M_2(\mathbb F)$ and $A \in \mathcal Ω$, then by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we have that $A^2=(trA)A-(detA)I_n$, and so we can conclude that for all positive integers $m$
$$A^{2m}=\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{(-1)^l\binom{2m-l-1}{l}(trA)^{2(m-l)-1}(detA)^l}\right)A-\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{(-1)^l\binom{2(m-1)-l}{l}(trA)^{2(m-l-1)}(detA)^{l}}\right)I_2,$$
and
$$A^{2m+1}=\left(\sum_{l=0}^m{(-1)^l\binom{2m-l}{l}(trA)^{2(m-l)}(detA)^l}\right)A-\left(\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{(-1)^l\binom{2m-l-1}{l}(trA)^{2(m-l)-1}(detA)^l}\right)I_2.$$
COMMENT
The above formulas also hold under the context of any commutative ring with multiplicative identity.
APPLICATION
Having in mind the previous comment, the golden ratio $φ$ and its conjugate $ψ$ are the only numbers that satisfy the following equation over $\mathbb R$: $x^2=x+1$. Thus, we have that for all $m \in \mathbb N$
$$φ^{2m+1}=φ\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}}+\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}},$$
$$ψ^{2m+1}=ψ\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}}+\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}},$$
and so if we subtract these equations, while having in mind that $φ-ψ=\sqrt{5}$, we get
$$F_{2m+1}=\sum_{l=0}^m{\binom{2m-l}{l}}.$$
In a similar spirit, we can also conclude that for all positive integers $m$
$$F_{2m}=\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}{\binom{2m-l-1}{l}},$$
where we used Binet's formula for the Fibonacci sequence.
QUESTION
Has this already been done?

Why are people downvoting this post?? It's a reference request!

It feels like this post is "announcing" a claim. Yes, it is true in any commutative ring that $z^2 = xz-\alpha$ implies $z^n=D_n(x,\alpha)-E_n(x,\alpha)+zE_{n-1}(x,\alpha)$, where $D_n$ and $E_n$ denote the Dickson polynomials. But the fact that "Dickson" is a 19th-century mathematician should already suggest trouble.

@KBDave Oh. I wasn't aware of these polynomials, but I guess whatever you do someone has already done it like a century ago :/ Anyway, I got what I needed. Thank you for this comment instead of another mysterious downvote :/

I found a reference, see McLaughlin, where the applications listed in the post have already been done. However, I did not find a reference of the above proposition, which was concluded independently from any other source.
